# Ajax call Doesn't access Partial Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

The current code only works if I remove the partial class (Def) and call AJAX by the public class name (PatientRegistration)

Please Help

```
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Web.Configuration
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
Imports AjaxControlToolkit
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic


Public Class PatientRegistration
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Partial Class Def
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
     <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Sub JSTblRegReadRec(ByVal FileNum As String)
        MsgBox(FileNum)
    End Sub
End Class
```

```html
<script>
       function JSTblRegReadRec() {
           $.ajax({
               type: 'POST',
               url: "Def.aspx/JSTblRegReadRec",
               data: '{FileNum: "' + $("#<%=FilenumSel.ClientID%>")[0].value + '" }',
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
           })
           .success(function (response) {
               alert(response.d);
           })
                   .error(function (response) {
                       alert(response.d);
                   });
       }
         
   </script>
```

The current code only works if I remove the partial class (Def) and call AJAX by the public class name (PatientRegistration)

thanks!